# Fragmentation error while executing C program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct table
{
    char *ipAddress;
    char *domainName;
    struct table *next;
};
struct table *head = NULL;
void add_rec();
void show_rec();
int main()
{
    add_rec();
    show_rec();
    return 0;
}

void add_rec()
{
    struct table * temp = head;
    struct table * temp1 = (struct table *)malloc(sizeof(struct table));
    if(!temp1)
     printf("\n Unable to allocate memory \n");

    printf("Enter the ip address you want \n");
    scanf("%s",temp1->ipAddress);

    printf("\nEnter the domain name you want \n");
    scanf("%s",temp1->domainName);

    if(!temp)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
         temp = temp->next;

        temp->next = temp1;
    }
}

void show_rec()
{
    struct table * temp = head;
    if(!temp)
     printf("\n No entry exists \n");

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("ipAddress = %s\t domainName = %s\n",temp->ipAddress,temp->domainName);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

When i execute this code and enters the IP address for the first node, i am facing fragmentation error. The code crashed. Can someone enlighten?

Comment: I think I can guess what you mean by a fragmentation error, but you should really be more specific. What is the exact error? Also, have you used a debugger or similar tool (I suggest valgrind), and what did it say?

Answer (score 2):

`ipAddress` is just a char pointer which is uninitialized. You've not allocated memory that could be pointed by `ipAddress`

When you do

```
scanf("%s",temp1->ipAddress);
```

It is expected that temp1->ipAddress points to a char array, which could be statically or dynamically allocated.

In your case you can change

```
char *ipAddress;
char *domainName;
```

to

```
char ipAddress[16]; // aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
char domainName[MAX_DOMAIN_LEN]; // choose max length suitably.
```

Also after you allocate a new node by doing a `malloc` you are not initializing the `next` pointer of the newly created node. You should be doing:

```
struct table * temp1 = (struct table *)malloc(sizeof(struct table));
temp1->next = NULL; // this is missing.
```

Also when the list is initially empty, `head` will be `NULL` so the if block will be executed. You should make `head` point to the newly created node, which is pointed by `temp1` not `temp`:

```
if(!temp)
{
  head = temp; // this should be head = temp1;
}
```